# Why can I not type in my Tkinter entry field

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I'm creating a simple form that allows the user to create cooking recipes and stores them in xml format.
So far things have gone great until I added a text entry widget to the form, to allow the user to put a short note in there. The text entry widget shows up with no issues, but no matter what I do I cannot type in it. I click in it and there is no cursor, and if I start typing, nothing shows up.

[Form Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LWllC.png)

Code for the offending entry widget:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3
import tkinter.filedialog
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox as db

#GLOBALS to be accessed from anywhere in the program flow
# list to store user choices
user_choices = ["blank"]


# Dicts to hold lookup values
flavors = {"Sweet":0, "Savory":1}
sav_dict = {"Beef":0, "Pork":1, "Pizza":2}
sweet_dict = {"Peach":0, "Apple":1, "Blueberry":2}

# Tuples of values for spinners
flavor_tup = "Sweet", "Savory"
savory_tup = "Beef", "Pork", "Pizza"
sweet_tup = "Peach", "Apple", "Blueberry"

#Function definitions, each should stand alone and be callable and able
#to manipulate and return any data sent to them.


# Choose your flavor, sweet or savory
def flavor_choice():
    profile = flavor_spin.get()
    if profile == "Savory":
        savory_spin.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)
        sweet_spin.pack_forget()
        user_choices[0] = 'savory'

    if profile == "Sweet":
        savory_spin.pack_forget()
        sweet_spin.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)
        user_choices[0] = 'sweet'


#popup to ask where to save the file
def file_chooser():
    myfile = tk.filedialog.asksaveasfilename(initialdir = "/", title = "Save in", filetypes = (("xml files", "*.xml"), ("all files", "*.*")))
    return myfile


# debug info method
def popup_message(msg):
    popup = tk.Tk()
    popup.wm_title("Information")
    label = tk.Label(popup, text=msg)
    label.pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10)
    B1 = tk.Button(popup, text="Okay", command = popup.destroy)
    B1.pack()
    popup.mainloop()


def another_rule():
    response=db.askquestion('Quit Now', 'Would you like to add another rule to the current ruleset?')
    if response == 'yes':
        popup_message("Please enter your next rule and click 'Submit'")
    if response == 'no':
        #Find out if the user would like to add a ruleset.
        another_ruleset()
        #call tail write
        #inform user what was done
        popup_message("All rules successfully written to {}".format(myfile))
        #close the program
        window.destroy()


def another_ruleset():
    response = db.askquestion('Quit Now', 'Would you like to add another ruleset to the current file?')
    if response == 'yes':
        file_write(myfile, "</ruleset>\n<ruleset>\n")
        popup_message("Added a new ruleset to your file")
        another_rule()
        # Go to rules section again
    if response == 'no':
        #pass tail data to file_write
        file_write(myfile, "\t</ruleset>")
        window.destroy()


def submit_recipe():
    if user_choices[0] == 'savory':
        answer = sav_dict[savory_spin.get()]
        #pass values to file_write
        str1 = "<" + savory_spin.get() + ">" + str(answer) + "</" + savory_spin.get() + ">\n"
        file_write(myfile, str1)
    if user_choices[0] == 'sweet':
        answer = sweet_dict[sweet_spin.get()]
        #pass values to file_write
        str1 = "<" + sweet_spin.get() + ">" + str(answer) + "</" + sweet_spin.get() + ">\n"
        file_write(myfile, str1)

    another_rule()


def file_write(myfile, contents):
    with open(myfile, "a") as mf:
        mf.write(contents)


#Create the GUI elements that the previous definitions will
#manipulate for user interaction.

# Create a window object
window = tk.Tk()

#Frame to go across top, hold spinners
top_frame = tk.Frame(master=window)
top_frame.pack()

# Frame at bottom to hold label for output
out_frame = tk.Frame(master=window)
out_frame.pack()
# Label to hold text output
out_label = tk.Label(master=out_frame, text="", height=10, width=40)
out_label.pack()

input_label = tk.Label(master=out_frame, text="String Input")
input_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
# Can't seem to enter anything in this entry box, only tested on windows.
str_entry = tk.Entry(master=out_frame)
str_entry.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
submit = tk.Button(master=out_frame, text="Submit", command=submit_recipe)
submit.pack(side=tk.RIGHT)


flavor_spin = tk.Spinbox(master=top_frame, values=flavor_tup, command=flavor_choice)
flavor_spin.pack(fill=tk.Y, side=tk.LEFT)
savory_spin = tk.Spinbox(master=top_frame, values=savory_tup)
sweet_spin = tk.Spinbox(master=top_frame, values=sweet_tup)


#main enry point for program logic flow
myfile = file_chooser()
#popup_message("You chose {}".format(myfile))
file_write(myfile, "<? XML 1.0>\n")
file_write(myfile, "\t<ruleset>\n")
file_write(myfile, "\t\t<rule>1</rule>\n")


# Run the event loop
window.mainloop()
```

I am using python 3.8.5 on a windows 10 machine, and am using the bare Tkinter that comes packaged with Python.

Comment: Can you please post your full code? The code doesnt work like this.

Comment: It works in my Python 3.8.5 on Windows 10.

Comment: This is probably due to some other code that is not here, are you using any text variables or something?

Comment: @CoolCloud I'm not using any variables in there yet. I was just going to use it's get() method to retrieve input when the submit button is pushed.

Comment: Can you post the entire code

Comment: all code is now posted

Comment: @jasonharper that fixed it perfectly. Thank you! I'm surprised that I didn't find that after all the searching I did but I greatly appreciate you steering me in the right direction. If you add as answer I'll accept it.